# Sharing session througout file_get_contents

Tags: php, session, file-get-contents

Good day, I would like to read a PHP executed file (with a session) from my server with PHP, but once I call file_get_contents by passing the session ID, it doesnt works:

To check, I made a small test on my server, here is the `test_reader.php` file:

```
session_start();

// if no test session, creating it & refreshing

if( !isset( $_SESSION['mysession'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION['mysession'] = 'hello world';
    header( 'Location: test_reader.php' );
}

// reading "test_readable.php"

$url = 'https://example.com/test_readable.php?';    

$parameters = http_build_query( array(
    'session' => session_id()
) );

$options = array( 'http' => array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'content' => $parameters
) );

$context = stream_context_create( $options );

echo ( $url.$parameters ).': <br>'.file_get_contents( ( $url.$parameters ), false, $context );
```

And here is the `test_readable.php` file:

```
// if session ID is sent, opening the session

if( isset( $_GET['session'] ) ) {
    session_id( $_GET['session'] );
}

session_start();

// checking result
    
if( isset( $_SESSION['mysession'] ) ) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no (id: '.session_id().')';
}

if( isset( $_GET['session'] ) ) {
    echo ' but session ID found';
}
```

First of all it takes a minute to load the `test_reader.php` when visiting it.

But in addition to this, there is no results at all:

```
https://example.com/test_readable.php?session=x75277c2a8fccfcc4d446ec7c93d84006:
```

Indeed, nothing from `test_readable.php` has been printed.

So I made a `var_dump` on the file_get_contents result to check the response:

```
bool(false)
```

And I don't understand why do my file is not read?

Do you know if it's coming from a session or a file_get_contents set up?
Or do you know where it can come from?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

**EDIT - TEST PRIVATE MODE FROM SCRATCH**

*test_reset.php*

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['mysession'] = null;
unset( $_SESSION['mysession'] );
session_destroy();
```

*test_readable.php*

```
// if session ID is sent, opening the session

if( isset( $_GET['session'] ) ) {
    session_id( $_GET['session'] );
}

session_start();

// checking result

if( isset( $_SESSION['mysession'] ) ) {
    echo 'yes (id: '.session_id().')';
} else {
    echo 'no (id: '.session_id().')';
}

if( isset( $_GET['session'] ) ) {
    echo ' and session ID found';
}
```

*test_reader.php*

```
session_id( 'session'.rand( 1, 9 ).rand( 1, 9 ).rand( 1, 9 ) );
session_start();

echo '<div>'.session_id().'&nbsp;</div>';

$_SESSION['mysession'] = 'hello world';

$parameters = http_build_query( array(
    'session' => session_id()
) );

$options = array( 'http' => array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'content' => $parameters
) );

$context = stream_context_create( $options );

$url = 'https://example.com/test_readable.php?';

$read = file_get_contents( ( $url.$parameters ), false, $context );
// $read = file_get_contents( ( $url.$parameters ) );

echo '<div>'.( $url.$parameters ).'&nbsp;</div>';

echo '<div>'.$read.'&nbsp;</div>';

var_dump( $read );
```

Test trace:

```
https://example.com/test_reset.php
>> <empty page>

https://example.com/test_readable.php
>> no (id: 59081a4dfd8ea3acd10ebaafd432daaf)

https://example.com/test_reader.php
>> session432 
>> https://example.com/test_readable.php?session=session432 
>> 
>> bool(false)
```

(Same result if I do not use the file_get_content with a context).

**EDIT 2 - TEST WITHOUT CONTEXT / SOLVED**

I didn't change other files, only the following-one:

*test_reader.php*

```
session_id( 'session'.rand( 1, 9 ).rand( 1, 9 ).rand( 1, 9 ) );
session_start();

$sessionID = session_id();
echo '<div>'.$sessionID.'&nbsp;</div>';

$_SESSION['mysession'] = 'hello world';
session_write_close();

$parameters = http_build_query( array(
    'session' => $sessionID
) );

$url = 'https://example.com/test_readable.php?';

$read = file_get_contents( ( $url.$parameters ) );

echo '<div>'.( $url.$parameters ).'&nbsp;</div>';

echo '<div>'.$read.'&nbsp;</div>';

var_dump( $read );
```

Result was:

```
https://example.com/test_readable.php
>> no (id: 2d3b1d3e9d2975134bf3141d3c49c3d8)

https://example.com/test_reader.php
>> session849 
>> https://example.com/test_readable.php? 
>> no (id: ce844dd021a0e1d167a316a2e4cd08a0) 
>> string(41) "no (id: ce844dd021a0e1d167a316a2e4cd08a0)"
```

Comment: Should help https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Pretty sure it would be a security risk to let the client set the session ID in this way.

Comment: _"Do you know if it's coming from a session or a file_get_contents set up?"_ - leaving file_get_contents out of it, and calling `https://example.com/test_readable.php?session=x75277c2a8fccfcc4d446ec7c93d84006` directly in your browser should be able to tell you _that_ quite quickly. (Try in a private window perhaps, to exclude that an actually existing session _cookie_ in the browser might otherwise falsify the result of this test.)

Comment: @CBroe calling `https://example.com/test_readable.php?session=x75277c2a8fccfcc4d446ec7c93d84006` directly in my browser works, I see this result: `yes but session ID found`, and calling `https://example.com/test_readable.php?session=abc` displays `no (id: abc) but session ID found`, so I guess my session set up is good, but it's coming from my file_get_contents function.

Comment: Your whole usage of the stream context makes little sense there. `content` specifies what is to be send as the request _body_ - but GET requests don't send their data in the body. You should completely remove the stream context, and then simply append your parameter to the URL.

Comment: @CBroe Just tested without the context (check port "edit"), but it doesn't seem to work without as well.

Comment: Your current code shows both, parameters appended to the URL, and still the the context with `content` for the request body. Please _remove_ the context, and test then.

Comment: And don't expect the `$_SESSION['mysession'] = 'hello world';` inside `test_reader.php` to show up in `test_readable.php`, if you are setting it for the first time here. The session of your current script has not even been _written_ yet, you'd need to call `session_write_close` for that to happen, so that the session actually reflects the current state when the request for `test_readable.php` is made. (Surprised this didn't time out with an error due to a lock on the session file here tbh.)

Comment: @CBroe, thank you so much for taking time to anwser. Indeed this solved my problem. I guess while I was testing my 1st version, the context was the problem. And once I removed it, I only needed to add session_write_close after initializing my session. Really appreciated your help!

Can I ask you to write it as an answer (not a comment) so I can flag your answer helpful, and this question solved please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of the stream context makes little sense there. `content` specifies what is to be send as the request body - but GET requests don't send their data in the body. You should completely remove the stream context, and then simply append your parameter to the URL.

And when using file-based session storage, PHP puts a lock on the session file, as long as one script instance is still "using" it. So trying to set the session value here in the same script that makes the request to the other one that is supposed to use the same session, will only properly work, if you call `session_write_close`, before you make the request. That writes all session changes out to the disk, and then releases the lock on the session file.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you destroyed the first session use this:

```php
 
session_abort(); // add this line

// set the new session
session_id( $_GET['session'] );

session_start();

// checking result
    
if( isset( $_SESSION['mysession'] ) ) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no (id: '.session_id().')';
}

if( isset( $_GET['session'] ) ) {
    echo ' but session ID found';
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, and I get the same result. I noticed a small difference in private mode: It doesn't stop loading.

Comment: You should change session before starting to send content. @LucasF

Comment: Thank you for your reply, as you can see, I sorted out this issue, you can have a look at the `EDIT 2` section of my question. But I appreciated your anwser!